What does Levinas' encounter with the Other mean/imply?
Levinas writes about ethics as the 'first' (most fundamental) philosophy - rather than ontology, epistemology or logic. He grounds ethics in our encounter with the Other (with capital 'O'). Ethical responsibility arises from personal encounters with (first of all) other humans, the face of the Other. This encounter somehow imposes an infinite responsibility and cannot be completely captured in particular systems of rules or ethical systems.
I have a very hard time making sense of those ideas. We all know that humans are social animals and that ethics pertains to social interactions. But apparently, Levinas wants to say more than that,
since, for instance, according to him, our responsibility is not (can not be) founded on reciprocity or mutual self-interest. I've a hard time not seeing these writings as a form of monotheistic Abrahamic religion disguised by the technical jargon of philosophy. "The Other" seems to come into play in a very similar way as Descartes' "idea of the infinite" enters into Descartes' Meditations and is used by Descartes to "escape" solipsism. As such it seems equally non-persuasive. (For instance, Descartes without real justification needs to assume that the infinite, God, is good and has no reasons to deceive us -- there is nothing "clear and distinct" about that assumption).
However, I can make some sense of these ideas if I metaphorically see another human being as either a demand, a promise or a threat. But is that all that is said in these ideas? And does this mean that, according to Levinas, those kind of notions ("(ethical) demand", "promise", "threat") are somehow primordial and don't allow further analysis? -- Is there an explanation of Levinas' core ideas that is not chock-full of abstract metaphysical jargon and makes it more accessible to simple-minded people like me? (I found even the SEP entry about Levinas largely incomprehensible.)

Before I say more I need to ask about: “I've a hard time not seeing these writings as a form of monotheistic Abrahamic religion disguised by the technical jargon of philosophy.” So you want an expressly non religious reading of him? But Levinas was an orthodox religious Jew who lectured for decades on the Talmud every Sabbat. It is very clear that he is in a deep essence sense (ie. not just the happenstance of birth) a Jewish philosopher just as Plantinga, Aquinas are Christian, Nagarjuna is Buddhist etc

See for example: https://www.hartman.org.il/weekly-shabbat-talks-by-emmanuel-levinas/

The more I read about him the more interesting it gets but also I realize (1) My own inadequacy to convey (2) The inadequacy of the SE format. Meanwhile, it's possible that Britannica is enough for your basic questions? Note particularly the comment: His life's philosophical project was to translate Hebrew into Greek

Thanks - I didn't think of a lookup in Brittanica :) The whole of philosophy from late Roman times to recent times has been shaped I think by a strange merger of Semitic religions (mostly Islam and Christianity) with Greek concepts -- as if each side didn't already have enough problems to express itself coherently, in the merger this became even more muddled. And it seems we're still dealing with the fall-out of that whole millenia-long process... :)

My favorite Russell quote: "Language is shot through with the faded hues of past philosophical theories." (I'd add to that: It seems some people still see those faded hues as the true colors of thought and reality.)

The SEP on Levinas is terrible — like some mediocre master's thesis which uses jargon to cover up lack of understanding

@Rushi - Yes,  I agree. But I think the real problem is that Levinas sort of invites this kind of in my eyes obscurantist writing... (Something went terribly wrong after Husserl, it seems. Husserl is still very understandable. But I don't really have a clue about what Heidegger for instance is even trying to do. Levinas is in that group - he seems to want to raise some fundamental criticism -- that much is clear to me --, but what is he really trying to say?)

Ive an paper to submit. So this must go on backburner. But as starter I recommend. Particularly on pg 13 Finkielkraut, realizing that he has to clarify his notion of innocence... for a few pages. I will for now only say this much: While I was earlier sceptical of «all these French postmodernists»,  I find now Levinas very significant in the current crisis in the middle-east. (Levinas was not just a Jew but in effect a Holocaust survivor)

Levinas is a bit hard to read, but you've already anticipated a connection between Levinas and Descartes regarding the idea of the infinite (though Levinas treats this in a different way), so you aren't totally off.
Ok, the short of it is that while Levinas is reacting to the entire western philosophical tradition (seeing himself as an anti-Parmenides), who he primarily targets is Husserl and Heidegger. As an older grad student said to me years ago, the key to (trying to) understand Levinas is to focus on the notion "mode of givenness." For example, past events are not given to us through perception, but in acts of recollection. Mathematical objects are not given in recollection but through act of conception or judgment, which correlates with the abstract objects that they are. The same holds for ethics.
That "the Other" is first and foremost ethical means that the mode of givenness is distinct from ordinary perceptual awareness. When you see a homeless man on the street, tired, dirty, ragged, you are immediately overcome with pangs of pain, and a "sense" of them yelling "Help me!" to you. You are called to act. The experience of this has a certain "nudity" to it, where the Other is given to me in a way without any reference to my autonomy as a rational agent, hence the entire selfless nature of the "call." Now, we can turn away from the homeless man and this is perhaps why many refuse to look such people in the eye: they don't want to experience the "call" from the Face of the Other.
For Levinas this is no metaphor or a feature of our social psychology: the Face of the Other has a manner of givenness sui generis, and cannot be reduced to the sort of transcendental psychology of Kant nor Husserl's time-consciousness. The Other transcends any anticipation or expectation: nothing can prepare you for this radical encounter of the nudity of the Other.
A moment on Descartes . . . Levinas treats the Face of the Other as a "trace of the infinite," such that the Other of the Other is God. We cannot behold God in any manner of givenness except, through the Face of the Other (fellow humans). The use of this monotheistic framework by Levinas is not to escape any philosophical puzzle  regarding radical skepticism, since our encounter with the Face of the Other already provides that escape, each time we encounter it in our experience.
Levinas ultimately rests on a fundamental principle of phenomenology that each mode of givenness (perceptual, imaginative, conceptual, and with Levinas the ethical) deserves to be grasped on its own terms. How much you agree with that will greatly impact how much you will accept the analysis Levinas provides at face value, or as reducible to something else (like social psychology). Unfortunately there isn't any specific work I can reference that will assist you except maybe to read the latter parts of his Time and the Other. While the beginning has the jargon you want to avoid, some of what he describes later about death and the immemorial past might be useful. Useful in that, he is trying to defend ethics as founded in a mode of givenness that is anterior to our autonomous rationality or rational agency.
